# String conversion to Array in Solidity

Tags: arrays, string, ethereum, solidity

In Solidity, is there a way I can convert my string text to an array using a separator to identify the composite parts within the string

Example

```
mystring = "This-Is-A-Problem";
```

to

```
myArray = [This,Is,A,Problem];   // using hyphen as separator
```

Comment: Food for thought: every operation in EVM costs gas (which is money), so while doing this is possible, I'd not recommend doing this kind of processing in EVM to save cost. You should do all of these processing offline (e.g. before passing it to the contract), and only use the contract to execute logic that must be done on the blockchain (e.g. storing values)

Comment: @Dat It comes down to priorities.  What costs more money, multiple oraclize_query calls returning single bits of data, or a single call that gets split it up in the contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Crema is almost correct, but note that for n parts we have n-1 delimiters. Modifying his code gives us:

```
import "github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/strings.sol";

contract Contract {
   using strings for *;

   // ...

   function smt() {
    var s = ""This-Is-A-Problem"".toSlice();
    var delim = "-".toSlice();
    var parts = new string[](s.count(delim) + 1);

    for(uint i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
       parts[i] = s.split(delim).toString();
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: This Strings Library fails to compile with my Contract, cause I'm using  `pragma solidity ^0.6.0;`  Is there no way for me to use it then?

Answer (score 3):

updated answer, works on latest compiler

```
import "github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/strings.sol";

contract Contract {                                                            
    using strings for *;                                                       

    function smt() public pure {                                               
        strings.slice memory s = "This-Is-A-Problem".toSlice();                
        strings.slice memory delim = "-".toSlice();                            
        string[] memory parts = new string[](s.count(delim));                  
        for (uint i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {                              
           parts[i] = s.split(delim).toString();                               
        }                                                                      
    }                                                                          
}
```

https://ethfiddle.com/TgY5JxLKvn

Comment: So, they dropped "var"?

Comment: they removed `var` in solidity 0.7.0 (current is 0.8.9) `The keyword var cannot be used anymore. Previously, this keyword would parse but result in a type error and a suggestion about which type to use. Now, it results in a parser error.` https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/070-breaking-changes.html?highlight=var#declarations

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in method/function for this but you can use [solidity-stringutils](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils). then

```
import "github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/strings.sol";

contract Contract {
    using strings for *;

    // ...

    function smt() {
        var s = ""This-Is-A-Problem"".toSlice();
        var delim = "-".toSlice();
        var parts = new string[](s.count(delim));
        for(uint i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
           parts[i] = s.split(delim).toString();
        }
    }
}
```